# Eclipse reverting java file to a much older version by itself?

Tags: eclipse

I have no idea how this happened but right after re-factoring a variable name (a final static int), the file showed a much earlier version of the same file **without any ability to restore back all the hours of work I put in**.

This looks like a bug to me or... "undocumented feature" (i.e. unfortunate key-combination that erases hours of work, even if stored on file)?

Has anyone experienced this?

Is this a well known behavior of Eclipse?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. What happens if you try to undo the refactoring ? For what it's worth I have never encountered anything similar. Also, do you not see a desirable version of the file in the local history of eclipse ?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal When I tried to undo the refactoring, only the refactoring was undone. Hours of changes that preceded it were simply lost. Where do I find that local history of Eclipse?

Comment: I have put the details of the local history in my answer below.

Comment: I have been hitting this bug ever since I started developing on a Mac. Is there a ticket for this in eclipse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Recovering work from Local History

Try recovering the lost work by using the 'Local History' feature of Eclipse.

Right click on a file and click on `Compare With -> Local History...` like so :

[image: Local History]

Once you do that, you should see a History view with timestamped entries like so :

[image]

Double clicking on those should allow you to go to a specific version of the File. You should be able to recover your work if you go to timestamped entry just before the apocalyptic refactoring.

For more details see **[this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm)** Eclipse help page.

#### Local History Preferences

This feature can be most useful to get back work which otherwise would be lost. In order to increase the amount of history per file (`Maximum Entries per file`) and the longevity of this history (`Days to keep Files`), try increasing the default values by going to `Preferences -> Workspace -> Local History` :

[image]

Comment: This is incredible! I didn't know about this feature. I can see versions going back to 24 hours ago. Is it possible that I somehow (unknowingly, via a key combination or a bug in the refactoring) triggered a version reversal? I will never know, so I am accepting your answer now.

Comment: @ateiob, I can't believe how many time this local history feature has been a lifesaver ! :) . I am glad it helped.

As far as I know, by default there is no shortcut to do an auto-reversal to previous version. The best there is a 'Revert File' option when you right click on a file. This reverts it to the last saved version. 

Also, if you find this feature useful, check out the last section titled `Local History Preferences` that I just updated my answer with.

Comment: I definitely find this useful. Next time something like this happens, I'll know what to do. Thanks!