# How to exit Eclipse without saving

Tags: eclipse, save

I have a lot of errors in Eclipse and want to revert without saving. Is there a way to exit Eclipse without saving?

Comment: You can just close it **but** maybe more helpful would be to right click and compareTo -> Local History

Comment: This is why SCCS are useful even if you're the only developer.

Comment: if i exit it will save automatically

Comment: @azurefrog *SCCS* Wow that is name from the past ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat Heh, I didn't mean literally SCCS (nowdays I use git), I mean just any Source Code Control System, but SCCS was the first SCCS I ever used.. ;-)

Comment: can i exit without saving what if i just ended the process  in task manager??

Comment: what happens if you try to click a windows with changes made - I guess it will prompt you to save or not.  **BUT** did you read my first comment?

Comment: im new to eclipse its easier for me to go from last save :/

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Eclipse: if you are seeing a bunch of new errors, that means your code has already compiled and thus has already been saved. 
You can [revert via local history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835510/eclipse-reverting-java-file-to-a-much-older-version-by-itself), however.

It is possible to turn off eclipse auto-saving before you attempt to run (and compile) your code... but that will just force you to manually save if you want to run (and compile) your code.

If you are adverse to using Version Control, you can always just duplicate your project as a new file before implementing major changes.